# pdfminer.six - Extract figures/images using `extract_pages` API

Tags: python, pdfminer

The Python library pdfminer.six allows you to extract images from a pdf using a [command line tool](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/images.html), but this doesn't appear very flexible.

It also allows you to iterate over elements in the document using the `extract_pages` API, and check if an item is of the type `pdfminer.layout.LTFigure`.

For example:

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTFigure, LTTextBoxHorizontal

figures = []

for page_layout in extract_pages(test_pdf):
    for element in page_layout:
        if isinstance(element, LTFigure):
            figures.append(element)
```

This seems like it will allow for control over how I work with images, but there is very limited documentation on the `LTFigure` object. Can I extract/save the image contained within?

Answer (score 0):

Body must be greater than 30 characters , you entered 0
https://gist.github.com/0187773933/47ae1f15a0d2e2d567890deecf9fce06

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).